# AutoMapper - Why it is overwriting whole object?

Tags: c#, automapper, dto, automapping, automapper-2

I don't understand why it's overwriting my whole object. The reason is that I get my `User` object from db an I want to assign new values from DTO. Instead of just adding those new values it's creating new object that has new values but all previous are set to `null`.

How can I make sure that in this case he will "upgrade" my object, not create new one?

## Scenario

`/users/{id}` - PUT

```
// User has id, username, fullname
// UserPut has fullname
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, UserPut userPut)
{
    var user = _db.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id); // filled with properties

    Mapper.CreateMap<UserPut, User>();
    user = Mapper.Map<User>(userPut); // now it has only "fullname", everything else set to null

    // I can't save it to db because everything is set to null except "fullname"

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, user);
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `Mapper.Map` has an overload which takes a source and **a destination** object. In this case Automapper will use the given destination object and does not create a new object.

So you need to rewrite your `Mapper.Map` to:

```
Mapper.Map<UserPut, User>(userPut, user);
```

Comment: Also note that you don't need to specify types as it takes the types of the two arguments.